# Issues manipulating css with react

Tags: css, reactjs

hope any of you could help me out in here...

On the code below I have 2 separete elements which I want to show one at the time.

first element is an iframe
second is a Div

the ideia is if the user click on the {title} then the frame disaper and the div appear.

I can manage to make the frame disapper and appear by clicking on the title, but the same does not happen with the div.

the code is basically the same, so I don't really get  why is the div not having the same behavior then the frame.

Also I double checked and both css classes get changed as expected, just that the css class seems not to work on the Div.

Tks in advance.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {
    const { id, title, active, site, img } = props.data;
    const [content, setContent] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className={`card ${active && 'active'}`} >
            <img id='img_cover' src={img} alt='image01' onClick={() => props.onCardClick(id)}></img>
            <div className='txt'>
                <h2 onClick={() => setContent(!content)}>{title}</h2>
            </div>
            <iframe className={`${content ? 'content_site' : 'content_frame'}`} src={site} frameborder="0" title={title}>
            </iframe>
            <div className={`${content ? 'content_frame' : 'content_site'}`}>
                <form id="contact-form" action="#" className="table">
                    <input className='input_espace row' id='nome' placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text" required />
                    <input className='input_espace row' id='email' placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" required />
                    <textarea id="text_area" className='row' cols="50" placeholder="Message" type="text" name="message" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning button_submit"> Enviar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}
export default Card;
```

Comment: Do you import your CSS because here you don't import it.

Comment: If you add CSS code too it will be helpful for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
className={`${content ? 'content_site' : 'content_frame'}`}
```

and

```js
className={`${content ? 'content_frame' : 'content_site'}`}
```

are contrandicting each other because both are expecting `content` to be true change one to be `!content`

change the second one as you can see in your method `setContent(!content)}`

like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {
    const { id, title, active, site, img } = props.data;
    const [content, setContent] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className={`card ${active && 'active'}`} >
            <img id='img_cover' src={img} alt='image01' onClick={() => props.onCardClick(id)}></img>
            <div className='txt'>
                <h2 onClick={() => setContent(!content)}>{title}</h2>
            </div>
            <iframe className={`${content ? 'content_site' : 'content_frame'}`} src={site} frameborder="0" title={title}>
            </iframe>
            <div className={`${!content ? 'content_frame' : 'content_site'}`}>
                <form id="contact-form" action="#" className="table">
                    <input className='input_espace row' id='nome' placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text" required />
                    <input className='input_espace row' id='email' placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" required />
                    <textarea id="text_area" className='row' cols="50" placeholder="Message" type="text" name="message" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning button_submit"> Enviar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}
export default Card;
```

Comment: Tks, it was those sily mistakes that you spend time with no reason. tks again

Comment: mistakes make us better